# "Человеческий глаз касается этих скромных строк" - так можно?

Tags: выбор-слов

Работа в архиве:

> С почтением перебирала фотографии табличек братских могил Гражданской,
>   осознавая, что, вероятно, **в последний раз человеческий глаз касается
>   этих скромных строк** — имя, две даты через тире. Многие могилы уже
>   тогда, в 70-х, терялись в бесконечных лугах и перелесках, а папки эти
>   будут лежать в самом низу, первыми в очередь на уничтожение.

.

Comment: Наверно, взгляд?! )

Comment: Пиши ответ. Меня и два слова устроят. Я не привередливая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, можно оставить — как есть.

> Когда глазами строк
>   твоих касаюсь
>   И мысль твоя вливается в меня,
>   Светлею я и к лучшему меняюсь
>   И с радостью иду на встречу дня.
>   [В. Аполлонов. Пушкину](http://www.invamagazine.ru/zl/2012/201202_15.htm)
>
> Не глазами, но сердцем
>   Строк касаюсь печальных –
>   Тех, что Герман Плисецкий
>   Не сумел напечатать.
>   [В. Амурский. Памяти Германа Плисецкого](http://magazines.russ.ru/kreschatik/2017/4/ne-o-bezumnoj-severnoj-koree.html)

Comment: Так то ж стихи...

Comment: Но ведь все понимают, что хотел сказать автор. Глаза _умеют говорить_ и даже лгать. Почему бы им не коснуться скромных строк?

Comment: Румулька-Л., спасибо. Я всё-таки поправила на взгляд. С другим моим вопросом давайте разбираться: я не вещь, ничто, - я любые разумные предложения приму: как выкрутиться, ибо, имхо, ТАК не пойдёт. Заумь какая-то.

Answer (score 1):

Хотя бы в кавычки надо поставить "касается": все ведь знают, что глаз видит только *на расстоянии* минимальной для него фокусировки. Иначе трудно отделаться от ощущения, что говорят о "прикладывании" глаза к строкам.

Answer (score 1):

*С почтением перебирала фотографии табличек братских могил Гражданской, осознавая, **что, вероятно,   в последний раз кто-то (вообще) касается глазами этих скромных строк** — имя, две даты через тире.*

Или ещё как-то исправить. ***Человеческий глаз*** — это сочетание по стилю не подходит: неприятно звучит, как что-то из медицинской терминологии.